Is there an order to the wifi network list or is it random?
Is there an order to how the Android OS displays Wifi Network Names in the Available Networks list?
Thanks

AFAIR on top are the networks you were connected to in the past (and that are reachable), afterwards all the other networks sorted by their signal strength.

Available Networks
The networks offered to connect are ordered by:

Being the primary network (isPrimaryNetwork())
Being connected to (getConnectedState())
Being a known network (instanceof KnownNetworkEntry)
Being a Hotspot Network provided via SharedConnectivityManager (instanceof HotspotNetworkEntry)
Displayed connection strength of the remote device to the internet (getUpstreamConnectionStrength())
Whether an entry shows a connect option (canConnect())
Whether an entry is for a subscription (isSubscription())
Whether an entry is for a saved configuration (isSaved())
Whether an entry is for a saved configuration (isSuggestion())
Signal strength (getLevel())
The title (getTitle())

using the WifiEntry.WIFI_PICKER_COMPARATOR
/**
 * Default comparator for sorting WifiEntries on a Wi-Fi picker list.
 */
public static Comparator<WifiEntry> WIFI_PICKER_COMPARATOR =
        Comparator.comparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !entry.isPrimaryNetwork())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) ->
                                entry.getConnectedState() != CONNECTED_STATE_CONNECTED)
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !(entry instanceof KnownNetworkEntry))
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !(entry instanceof HotspotNetworkEntry))
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> (entry instanceof HotspotNetworkEntry)
                                ? -((HotspotNetworkEntry) entry).getUpstreamConnectionStrength() : 0)
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !entry.canConnect())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !entry.isSubscription())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !entry.isSaved())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> !entry.isSuggestion())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> -entry.getLevel())
                .thenComparing((WifiEntry entry) -> entry.getTitle());

in WifiPickerTracker::updateWifiEntries()
activeWifiEntries.sort(WifiEntry.WIFI_PICKER_COMPARATOR);

In residential areas often many of the upper criterias will be the same and the UpstreamConnectionStrength/signal strength will be the decisive factors.
Saved Networks
The saved networks in Wi-Fi > Advanced > Managed networks are ordered alphabetically by title using the WifiEntry.TITLE_COMPARATOR
public static Comparator<WifiEntry> TITLE_COMPARATOR =
                Comparator.comparing((WifiEntry entry) -> entry.getTitle());

in SavedNetworkTracker::updateWifiEntries()
mSavedWifiEntries.addAll(mStandardWifiEntryCache);
Collections.sort(mSavedWifiEntries, WifiEntry.TITLE_COMPARATOR);

